# Using the % percent sign in lstlisting breaks text coloring

Tags: color, lstlisting

In my `lstlisting`, If I use a `%` sign, the highlighting for the rest of the file no longer works.

```
\subsection{Dereferencing pointers}
\par When you dereference a pointer, you are going to the memory address, and grabbing the piece of
information from there. 
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
printf("%p", pAge); 
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{why use pointers?}
```

Here is what it looks like in LaTeX.

[image]

You can see that the `subsection` on the very first line is purple and there is no highlighting of `lstlisting` in the first `\begin{lstlisting}` but then right after adding the `%` sign, the `lstlisting` became highlighted indicating it is spelled wrong, and the `\subsection` at the very last line is not in purple text.

As soon as removing the `%` signs, it is fixed. Also, when I add `\` before each `%` the problem is also fixed but then the backslash shows up in the compiled version which I don't want.

Here is my lstlisting style definition:

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
breakatwhitespace=false,         
breaklines=true,                 
captionpos=b,                    
keepspaces=true,                 
numbers=left,                    
numbersep=5pt,                  
showspaces=false,                
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,                  
tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle, escapeinside={|}{|}}
```

Comment: `%` is a reserved character in (La)TeX which indicates a comment.  Have you tried `\%` (to escape the character)?

Comment: Yes, however when I use `\%` then the \ also shows up in the compiled pdf file, which I do not want. Is there no way to prevent that from happening? I thought `lstlisting` prints the text verbatim and as a result wouldn't change anything outside of the environment.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that you indicated that.  By the way, it would be helpful to make this into a complete minimal working example rather than a code snippet.

Comment: So I just realized that if I do `|\%|` then I can get just % to show up without messing up text color in the editor but then in the pdf, `%` is not purple like the text should be; this also doesn't seem to be a very good solution.

Comment: Do you mean in your editor? It's just your editor getting confused in its syntax highlighting because it thinks you have mismatched parentheses. The editor doesn't know about code listings. So it thinks that `\printf(` gives an open parenthesis. Then there is a `%` comment character, so it doesn't see the closing parenthesis. I don't know what you can do about this other than use a different editor.

Comment: From the picture this seems to be purely an issue of your editor. Apparently the `%` messes up its code highlighting (because it does not realise that `listings` is a verbatim environment where `%` is not a comment). This has nothing to do with how LaTeX handles the input. You could contact the developer of the TeX code highlighting for your editor or the developer of your editor (you don't mention which editor you use in your question) and maybe they can fix that, if not either ignore this unfortunate behaviour or use another editor.

Comment: I run into the same problem. Is there a solution?